# How to skip intro videos in MGS5:Ground Zeroes for PC?

Tags: pc, metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

Is there a command line argument or something for Metal Gear Solid V: Ground Zeroes on PC (Steam) to skip the intro videos, like there are in other games?

(I'm not talking about the mission intro cutscene - I'm talking about the Konami/NVidia/etc splashes when you first load the game)

Thanks.

Comment: You can dismiss each logo by pressing a key (or button, if you use a controller). The Konami logo can't be dismissed that way, though, and you still have to wait for the logos to appear. You just no longer have to wait for them to _disappear_ again.